# Show Floating Div on mouse over

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple configuration where I'm using a left panel, with a hover placeholders, when I hover a place holder (ex. links) I show a floating div in the right side

All is working just fine, except for **Safari** where the floating div is not shown.

See an example of the sources here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXPPg/)

I've figured that the problem is coming because I gave the **#left-panel** an

```
overflow: auto;
```

but when I remove this rule, I can no longer see the content that is hidden from the **#left-panel**

Can anybody suggest anything?

#### EDIT

Just a note, it is working fine in the most versions of: Firefox, Chrome, Opera, the problem only in **Safari (7)**

#### Important

Even if I would enjoy using some plugins, for performance issues, I'm stick on using pure javascript code and css. any css rule to solve that is the solution I would go for

### some screenshots - after hover:

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Opera

[image: Opera]

Safari

[image: Safari]

Comment: why don't you use tooltip ?? :)

Comment: the content I'm showing is very complicated, might contains sliders and some other stuff, I've only put an example to explain my problem

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae there are lots of tooltip plugins which allow for complex HTML structure in the tip. Qtip2 for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, for performance issues, I can't use any plugin, in my real project I'm not even using jquery (just plain js), since we have problems in performance every msecond is important

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle in Safari and Firefox and had the same result.

Comment: Which Safari version do you have? can you see the orange div when you hover the link?

Comment: `in my real project I'm not even using jquery (just plain js),` **well you are using jQuery in your FIDDLE and you tagged jQuery for this Question ..why is so...**

Comment: as I said in a the second comment: `I've only put an example to explain my problem`

Comment: You can use CSS to achieve a tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/zuTDp/

Comment: try with absolute position instead of fixed.

Comment: @StefanDunn I've double checked you jsfiddle, and I guess I can't use it, because my floating div will have much more complicated content than only text

Comment: Setting `position:fixed` to `position:asbolute` for `#left-panel` fixes the problem for me. Is it necessary to have a fixed position?

Comment: @StefanDunn it does fix things in the example I've set, but not in my real project, I'll see whats different then come back with updates, thanks for your support :)

Comment: I think you are confused as to the difference between javascript and JQuery. JQuery is a javascript library.

Comment: @StefanDunn why don't you answer with the `position:absolute` settings, I would gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `position:fixed` to `position:asbolute` for #left-panel fixes the problem for me. Is it necessary to have a fixed position?

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a comment, but it would not let me add a comment.  Try using absolute positioning and position the block entirely off the window; when the user mouses over, position the block to where you want it on the page.  You can use CSS for this.

Here is a page on w3.org that shows how to do this for an accessibility issue: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/G201.